# Closed good cover of a triangulable space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-complexes

By a good closed cover of a topological space $X$, I mean a collection of closed subspaces of $X$, such that the interior of them cover $X$, and any finite intersection of these closed subspaces is contractible.

Every triangulable space $X$ admits a good open cover: just fix a triangulation and take open stars at all vertices. As for closed stars, the interior of closed stars cover $X$, but the intersection of closed stars can be non-contractible, as the simple example of the circle  (3 vertices, 3 segments) shows: the intersection of two different closed stars is the disjoint union of a segment and a vertex. However, after taking barycentric subdivision, we get 6 vertices and 6 segments in the circle, and the closed stars now form a good closed cover.

My question is: is it true that after iterated barycentric subdivisions, the closed stars of a triangulated space will form a good closed cover? (If not, is it true for finite / locally finite geometric simplicial complexes?)

Thank you!

Comment: Your example is not a triangulation. In a triangulation, a simplex is determined by its vertices. This is where your issue comes from.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I have updated the question. The issue still exists.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I think one subdivision should suffice (but don't immediately see a nice concise proof).

Comment: I expect in your first sentence you really mean that the finite intersections are either contractible or empty. I'm not sure about closed stars. But you could cover your simplicial complex $K$ by taking, for each maximal simplex $\sigma\in K$, the simplicial neighborhood $N(\sigma)$ in the second barycentric subdivison of $K$. These neighborhoods are all contractible, since they deformation retract to the simplices themselves, and furthermore they have the magical property that $N(\sigma) \cap N(\tau) = N(\sigma \cap \tau)$ (again contractible, since $\sigma\cap \tau$ is a simplex).

Comment: If the above sounds useful to you, and you'd like some further details, let me know. In brief, the deformation retraction property is classical but I don't know a direct proof in the literature. It is easy to prove using Quillen's Fiber Theorem (aka Theorem A). The intersection property becomes obvious if you write out in detail what these simplicial neighborhoods are, as chains of chains of simplices of $K$: $N(K) = \{C : min(min \, C) \in K\}$, which is equal to the order complex of the subposet $\{C : min \, C \in K\}$ of the order complex of the face poset of $K$.

Comment: (It's lucky for the second barycentric subdivision that it's such a contruction, because it is sure an awful thing to talk about.)

Comment: @DanRamras Yes, I meant every nonempty finite intersection is contractible. What you said is useful to me, thank you! I should not have restricted my question to closed stars but I was expecting that would give a solution to my real question: find a collection of subcomplexes, possibly after barycentric subdivision, which forms a good closed cover.

Comment: @DanRamras I am not familiar with your notation $min$, but is it true that for an original simplex $\sigma$ in $X$ (whether $\sigma$ is maximal or not), $N(\sigma)$ is the union of the closure of simplices in the second barycentric subdivision of $X$ that meet $\sigma$?

Comment: @Yeah: Indeed, $N(\sigma)$ means what you said. Another way to say it, combinatorially, is that $N(\sigma)$ consists of all (closed) simplices (in the second barycentric subdivision) that are contained in a simplex that meets $\sigma$. Note that $\sigma$ now refers to a subcomplex of the second barycentric subdivision (namely the second barycentric subdivision of $\sigma$ itself). And $min$ is just the function that sends a chain to its miniumum element.

Comment: @Yeah: I'll try to write a real answer soon. (Feel free to email me about this. I happen to be working on something where I needed this, so I have a write-up. But it might still need editing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Claim:** Let $Z$ be a simplicial complex. For each simplex $\sigma\in Z$, let $N_2 (\sigma, Z)$
denote the simplicial neighborhood of $\sigma$ (or really, the second barycentric subdivision of $\sigma$)
inside the second barycentric subdivision of $Z$. Then
$\{|N_2 (\sigma, Z)|: \sigma \in Z\}$ is a good cover of $|Z|$.

Before discussing the proof, let's fix terminology and notation. Here a simplicial complex will mean a set $K$ such that each element $\sigma\in K$ is a non-empty finite set, and such that $\sigma'\subseteq \sigma \in K$ implies $\sigma'\in K$ (unless $\sigma' = \emptyset$). The geometric realization of a simplicial complex will be denoted $|K|$.

The subdivision of a simplicial complex $K$ is the simplicial complex $sd (K)$ whose elements are the non-empty chains (totally ordered subsets) of $K$. (Here we are implicitly viewing $K$ as a poset under set-theoretic inclusion; this will keep happening.) Iterating the barycentric subdivision functor $n$ times gives $sd^n (K)$ (and $sd^0 K := K$). It will be useful to consider the function $min: sd^n (K) \rightarrow sd^{n-1} K$, which sends a chain to its minimum element. This is an order-reversing function (but not a simplicial map). We'll also use the composite function $min^2 = min\circ min : sd^2 K\to K$; this is order-preserving.

If $K \subseteq Z$ is a subcomplex, the simplicial neighborhood of $K$ in $Z$ is defined by

$N(K, Z) := \{\sigma\in Z : \exists \tau \in Z, \sigma \subseteq \tau \supseteq \kappa \in K\}.$

If $K$ is a subcomplex of $Z$, then $sd^m K$ is a subcomplex of $sd^m Z$, and we simplify notation by defining

$N_m (K, Z) := N(sd^m K, sd^m Z).$

The arguments below are all very simple, but can be quite confusing to read because we have to keep track of things like the difference between a simplex $\sigma \in K$, a 1-element chain $\{\sigma\} \in sd K$, and a 1-element chain $\{\{\sigma\}\} \in sd^2 K$ whose single element happens to itself be a 1-element chain.

I recommend thinking of elements $C \in sd^2 Z$ as 2-dimensional arrays, where each column is a chain of simplices in $Z$ and moving from left to right, we simply add more elements to the chain.

**Lemma 1:**  For any subcomplex $K$ of a simplicial complex $Z$, we have

$N_2 (K, Z) = \{ C \in sd^2 Z : min^2 C \in K\}.$

Moreover, this simplicial complex is precisely the order complex of the subposet $P_1 (K, Z)\subseteq sd Z$ defined by

$P_1 (K, Z) := \{c \in sd Z : min(c) \in K\}.$

**Note:** By the order complex of a poset $P$, I just mean the set of (finite) non-empty chains in $P$. Note here that $P_1 (K, Z)$ is not a simplicial complex (in general), so in particular it's not a subcomplex of $Z$. But for each subset $P \subseteq Z$, the  set of chains in $P$ is a subcomplex of $sd Z$.

Proof: We prove containment in both directions. Say $C\in N_2 (K, Z)$. Then we have $C \subseteq D \supseteq E$
for some $D \in sd^2 Z$ and $E \in sd^2 K$. Since $min$ is order-reversing, $D \supseteq E$ implies $min(D) \subseteq min(E)$, and since $min(E) \in sd K$ we have $min(D) \in sd K$ as well. Similarly,

$C\subseteq D \Longrightarrow   min^2 C \subseteq min^2 D$.

But $min(D) \in sd K$ implies $min^2 D \in K$, so $min^2 C\in K$ as well.

The reverse inclusion is simpler. Say $C \in sd^2 Z$ and $min^2 C \in K$. Let $C_0' = \{min^2 C\} \in sd K$, and note that $C_0' \subseteq min(C)$, so $\{ C_0'\}\cup C\in sd^2 Z$. We now have

$C \subseteq \{ C_0'\}\cup C  \supseteq   \{ C_0' \}
\in sd^2 K,$

showing that $C\in N_2 (K, Z)$.

Finally, note that if $C\in sd^2 Z$ and $min^2 C \in K$, then in fact
$min (c) \in K$ for all $c\in C$, because for each $c\in C$,

$min(C) \subseteq c \implies min(c) \subseteq min^2 C \in K.$

Thus $N_2 (K, Z)$ is the order complex of the poset $\{c \in sd Z :  min(c) \in K\}$. QED

Here is an immediate but useful consequence of the above characterization of neighborhoods:

**Lemma 2:** If $Z$ is a simplicial complex and $K, L\subseteq Z$ are subcomplexes, then $N_2(K, Z) \cap N_2 (L, Z) = N_2 (K\cap L, Z)$.

The following is classical and well-known, although I don't know where to find an elementary proof in the literature.

**Lemma 3:** For any subcomplex $K$ of a simplicial complex $Z$, the inclusion $sd^2 K \hookrightarrow N_2 (K, Z)$ is a homotopy equivalence.

**Proof:** It is sufficient to check that the inclusion $i : sd K \hookrightarrow P_1 (K,Z)$ satisfies the hypotheses of Quillen's Fiber Theorem (aka Theorem A) - that is, it suffices to show that the Quillen fibers are all contractible.
For each $c\in P_1 (K, Z)$, the Quillen fiber "under" $c$ is just $\{d \in sd K : d \subseteq c\}$, and has $c\cap K$ as its maximum element (note that $c\cap K$ is non-empty, as $c\in P_1 (K, Z)$ implies $\min (c)\in c\cap K$). Every poset with a maximum element has contractible realization. QED

**Aside:** This argument actually leads to the stronger conclusion that $K \hookrightarrow N_2 (K, Z)$ is a simple homotopy equivalence, by a result of Barmak in *On Quillen's Theorem A for posets* ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.0538), [J. Comb. Theory Ser. A](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcta.2011.06.008)).

Now we can prove the Claim regarding good covers:

**Proof of Claim:** For each simplex $\sigma\in Z$, there is a corresponding subcomplex of $Z$, which we also denote by $\sigma$, consisting of all non-empty subsets of $\sigma$. Since $|\sigma|$ is contractible, Lemma 3 implies that $|N_2 (\sigma, Z)|$ is contractible as well. Moreover, Lemma 2 (and induction) shows that every finite intersection $\bigcap_i |N_2 (\sigma_i, Z)|$ has the form $|N_2 (\bigcap_i \sigma_i, Z)|$, and  $\bigcap_i \sigma_i$ is either empty or is just (the subcomplex corresponding to) another simplex. So $\bigcap_i |N_2 (\sigma_i, Z)|$ is either empty or contractible. QED